# How do you make a Gravity effect?

Tags: combat, character-creation, powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I've been doing character building exercises in M&M3e so I can have a better grasp on the Dos and Don'ts of the system.

I was thinking of that one scene from *Batman Beyond* where the one villain is becoming more and more intangible as the week progresses, until the point where he just falls straight to the center of the earth. Between that and Space Gear that lets you stand normally on surfaces in the void, I feel like it's a valid power to be familiar with.

That being said, **how do I make a Gravity Power that's an affliction or a movement power?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities, of course, but if you're looking for simple builds:

- **Affliction** - This is just a matter of deciding what conditions you want. For easy reference, I built a list of [Affliction Conditions](https://roninarmy.com/forum/atomic-think-tank/mutants-masterminds-rules/442-affliction-conditions) on the Ronin Army site. If you want to focus on the "keeping people from moving" side of things, then Hindered / Immobile / Paralyzed is probably the trio of conditions you want. Alternately, for modeling difficulty in fine movements, you could do Impaired / Disabled / Incapacitated. Prone makes a pretty fine 2nd tier condition to add.
- **Movement** - Flight. That's pretty much the easiest thing to do, describing the flight as adjusting gravity to move you in a particular direction, or to stay in place.

That said, the *Batman Beyond* episode you're working form was largely about intangibility with the gravity being a nasty side effect of him being unable to avoid sinking into the ground (and not having an ability to not be affected by gravity.

If I've misunderstood your question, please correct me.

Ah, and if you're looking to not have to put as much work into rolling your own, Green Ronin published a *[Power Profiles: Gravity Powers](https://greenroninstore.com/products/mutants-and-masterminds-power-profile-gravity-powers-pdf?_pos=1&_sid=57c196245&_ss=r)* booklet, the contents thereof also available in the *[Power Profiles](https://greenroninstore.com/products/power-profiles-pdf?_pos=1&_sid=6056e4963&_ss=r)* collection, or in the Power Profiles add-on for Hero Lab. Fair warning, *Power Profiles* are kind of second-degree canon. They're an official release, but they are not "Core Rules" and they were written up by different authors with some contradiction occurring as a result.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information. As for the **Batman Beyond** example, it was the first thing that came to mind that couldn't be done with a telekinesis power. that being said, as soon as I knew the base structure of a gravity power, my intent was to link it with intangibility to better simulate the example I gave. Problem was I couldn't state that without triggering an Opinion Hold from the site, again sorry for the confusion